# Is there a way in Rails 6.X to read secret_key_base from an environment variable in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have SECRET_KEY_BASE set up as an environment variable in production and everywhere I need it in my code, I read it from the environment. But when I try to deploy, during asset recompilation, I get:

```
ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `bin/rails credentials:**REDACTED**
```

Is there a way to make Rails read it from the environment variable? I'm searching for something similar to having `secrets.yml` with:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

without having to have an encrypted file in my repo and having to maintain that key.

Comment: rails is already reading it from the environment https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.7.6/railties/lib/rails/application.rb#L438

Answer (score -1):

Although, as mentioned in the comments, the `ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` will override any other setting (in production), the whole idea of having that encrypted file is so that you **can** store it in the repo along with everything else. You then just manage the single `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` env var, which allows you to use that credentials file to store other secrets and only have to manage a single key.

The rationale as per the `rails credentials:help` help:

> === Storing Encrypted Credentials in Source Control
>
> The Rails `credentials` commands provide access to encrypted
> credentials, so you can safely store access tokens, database
> passwords, and the like safely inside the app without relying on a
> mess of ENVs.
>
> This also allows for atomic deploys: no need to coordinate key changes
> to get everything working as the keys are shipped with the code.